# jQuery saving Time and expiraton date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to know how I can save a date format in jQuery.

Today I had an idea to save a COOKIE by using jQuery.

After I had a look at the content of a COOKIE from another site I saw that it will be stored the date.

As I tried to do the same for my site I used this code:

```
$.cookie('name', new Date(), { expires: 365 });
```

The COOKIE will be set but with the difference that the content will be displayed in a strange format like this:

```
Thu%20Nov%2007%202013%2020%3A04%3A49%20GMT%2B0100%20(CET)
```

When I read out the COOKIE by using:

```
alert( $.cookie('name') );
```

It will display the date format correctly. So my first question is how can I save a date in the correct form like:

> Thu Nov 7 2013 20:04:49 GMT+0100 (CET)

instead of that strange format from above.

And my second question is how to set an expiration date format that it will end on a specific time.
At this point It will expire on

> Nov 7 2014 20:04:49 GMT+0100 (CET)

but how can I let it expire for example on

> Nov 7 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

?

Thanks alot.

UPDATE:

this is the Code I use:

```
...
var now = new Date();
var expireDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

$.cookie('cookiePolicyConsent', new Date().toString(), { expires: expireDate }); 
...
```

it does not save the COOKIE. The rest of the Code still works. Only this lines dealing with the COOKIE.

Comment: "that strange format" ... u mean URI encoded. You can just use the `decodeURI()` function to get the string version.

Comment: If you get the value back in the correct format, why do you care how it's stored?

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:**

Use [toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp) if you just want to store the text. I agree with the comment above... does it really matter how it is stored as long as you get the correct value back? If you don't want to put the date object in the cookie then you can use .UTC() or .getTime()

There are several other toString functions on the date object that will help you get it in the format you want: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

**Second question:**

You can pass in a date instead of number with the "expire" property. So you could do something like:

```
var now = new Date();

// Expire the cookie tonight at midnight
var expireDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 1);

$.cookie('name', new Date().toString(), { expires: expireDate });
```

Comment: hi, and where do you use the toString function? BTW it does not save at all. thanks

Comment: So you'd do something like this: 
```var myDate = new Date(); 
$.cookie('name', myDate.toString(), { expires: expireDate });
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? What isn't working? That code will get you a string....  

If you are copy/pasting that code from my previous comment you will need to create expireDate or change it to be a number.

Comment: the whole code does not work. when setting a variable with the expireDate i.e. it does not save the expiration date. Or even using the tostring function ddoes not convert it into a string. its like before.

Comment: I didn't add toString() to the date. I updated the code in "Second Question"

Comment: I just tried using toString in my console and it works fine. Can you update the question with your code so I can see what you are doing?

Comment: Maybe you need to include the path:'/' value in that object?
According to the authors website what you have should work unless you are using it on another page in your site: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Another thing... you will probably need to add a day to the expireDate since it will already be expired (it is using midnight Nov 7, 2013 which has already passed). I updated my example.

Comment: Did you update the expire date to be like my example? I changed it to expire tonight at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier if you save the date in millisecond like so

```
$.cookie('name', new Date().getTime(), { expires: 365 });
```

and then when you retrieve it

```
alert( new Date($.cookie('name')) );
```